# How much memory does the 23LC1024 have?

Tags: microchip, ram, sram

The Microchip [23LC1024](https://eu.mouser.com/pdfDocs/Microchip_Serial_SRAM.pdf) chip is said to have 1Mbit of memory. Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabit), it says that a Mbit is 10^6 bits. Is that so? I mean, is this decimal Mbit? It doesn't seem reasonable to me..

Comment: Why would you rely on Wikipedia vs. the Microchip data sheet?

Comment: @jwh20 The problem is not Wikipedia, the problem is not reading the full article or considering the context. The article does mention that in the semiconductor industry, it is still common practice to use binary interpretation for memory sizes so that a megabit means 2^20.

Answer (score 5):

It has 2^20 bits of memory, as shown by datasheet:

- 128K * 8-bit organization == 1024K bits
- 4096 pages of 32 bytes == 131072 bytes == 1048576 bits
- 24-bit addressing, with 7 unused bits == 17 address bits == 131072 bytes
- Highest address 1FFFFh == 131072 bytes